# python os.system got my long command trim into two lines

Tags: python, os.system

```
import os
cmd =str("./xtool -l ./temp_files/"+file1+ " -t "+line+" -json -o "+result_file)
os.system(cmd)
```

Im trying to run this command with python but the code got trimmed because of long files names
so it read up to **"+line+"** and any things else after read as new command so I got error like this
`sh: 2: -json: not found`

Comment: What is `line`? Does it include a newline? Please read [mre]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is no new lines in file.

Comment: It is better to used pathlib instead of os.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by adding `line.strip()`

`cmd=f'./tools/nuclei -l {urlsList} -t {line.strip()} -json -o {results}'`